# What is the key scheme used in the hypercore protocol?

Tags: public-key-encryption, hypercore-protocol

**What is the key scheme used in the [hypercore protocol](https://hypercore-protocol.org/protocol/)?**

I didn't find a quick/good answer on searching so adding the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/)

From [here](https://datprotocol.github.io/how-dat-works/):

> Public key. An ed25519 public key unique to this Dat, used by the
> author to create and update data within it. The public key enables you
> to discover other peers who have the data and verify that the data was
> not corrupted or tampered with as it passed through the network.